# is it possible to use class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pretty new in ASP.NET, so forgive me, When I drop an element from toolbar, it comes with an ID. Just wondering if it's possible I create a div class, and use it like `.box2` and give commands like `box2.Visible=false;` ?

```
<style>
    #box2
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
    <div runat="server" id="box2"></div>
</form>



protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (box2.Visible == true)
    {
        box2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        box2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can not perform any action from server side on basis of class name. You have to use id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible. You have to use Id with any server side controls

Answer (score 0):

No, class is client side, use for css and javascript. You can access element with ID if `runat="server"` is assigned to control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's tricky but it can be done.

```
public static class Methods
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return control;
            foreach (Control descendant in GetAllControls(control))
            {
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
}



var securedControls = Helpers.Methods.GetAllControls(this)
                                      .OfType<WebControl>()
                                      .Where(c => c.CssClass == "box2 ");
```

With this you'll IEnumerable of controls in the aspx page where CssClass = box2, loop over them and set their visibility.